# Transimpedance and resistor bias in IR transmitter

Tags: photodiode, transimpedance

I've been studying the optical (photo-diode) transmitter and receiver circuit for a while. There's a case that I can't understand the difference. In the optical receiver bias circuit, what is the difference between resistance bias and transimpedance ?

[image]

Comment: The most obvious difference is that the amplifier provides active gain, whereas the resistor does not.  If you have a small signal you might want that gain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what is the difference between resistance bias and transimpedance ?

- transimpedance amplifier inverts the output: more light causes
  *higher output voltage* while the resistor output causes a *lower output voltage*.
- looking at the output side of OP's circuits:
  transimpedance provides a very low output Thevenin resistance: (<<47k)
  resistance circuit output Thevenin resistance is 47k
- the opamp circuit is a potential oscillator (because of its gain)
  the resistive circuit can never oscillate
- resistive circuit has frequency response determined by the parallel combination of the 47k resistor and (photodiode capacitance plus load capacitance).
- opamp circuit has an extended frequency response that depends on op amp gain-bandwidth product...load capacitance's effect is diminished.